# htaccess url rewriting conflict between line code

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem here between this two code

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Hide File Extentions
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
RedirectMatch 301 ^/buzz/(.*)$ http://buzz.perghhh.com/$1
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^buzz/([^/]*)$ /buzz.php?buzz=$1 [L]
```

When I entered a url like this http://example.com/buzz/17
It acts like I'm going to a profile page..

Comment: Why are you declaring `RewriteEngine On` twice?

Comment: There must be some other rewrites affecting this. How big is the `.htaccess` file? Can you post it?

Comment: I accidentally duplicated it before posting this.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard view my full code here http://pastebin.com/YvSxiNYd

Comment: I moved the full block of rewrites over here because it is all relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the linked full htaccess you have the following redirection:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/buzz/(.*)$ http://buzz.perghhh.com/$1
```

That redirection to `/$1` will also be matched by the generic rule `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)` after it completes. Since you also have the `^buzz/([^/]*)$` rewrite, it seems like the previous `RedirectMatch` should not be present. If you want to match `buzz/xxxx`, use only the `RewriteRule` and not the `RedirectMatch`.

Further, Apache's rewrite rules are processed by first match, so `buzz/` with nothing following it matches the  generic `profile.php` rule.  You just need to move it above the generic rules. Always place specific rules before generic ones.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^buzz/([^/]*)$ /buzz.php?buzz=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I have also replaced the second `profile.php` rule by simply adding an optional trailing `/` with `/?` to the first one.

Comment: I'm waiting for you answer *Edit: I have followed your instructions but it turned to a 500 error .

Comment: Doesn't mind . I have changed the RedirectMatch to RewriteRule and it gives me an error, 500

Comment: @SyareezZainal Don't change it to a RewriteRule, remove the RedirectMatch entirely.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Okay, I have removed the RedirectMatch entirely but it give me an error when I go to the `buzz/xxx`

Comment: @SyareezZainal If you get a 500 you must check your error log to find the reason. and if it is a rewrite loop, you must check your access_log to see what URLs are being requested.

Comment: I have checked the both file but its empty .

Comment: You have several other rewrite rules farther down in your long htaccess. You need to debug this by commenting them out to test. Change `[L]` temporarily to `[L,R]` to force redirects and see what URL is actually being written.  We cannot do much more to help you here. The apparent problems are already noted in my answer.

Comment: @DomutaMarcel you are incorrect about that.  The hyphen -  may be placed at the end of a character class unescaped, where it it treated unambiguously as a literal hyphen, not as a range. Both the underscore and hyphen in that context are literals.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^buzz/([^/]*)$ /buzz.php?buzz=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

You end the rows with [L] which mean that this will be the (L)ast rule and `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$` is more inclusive and will include buzz as well.